# junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Exception occured : java.lang.ClassCastException:

Tags: mockito, powermockito

Getting error 
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Exception occured : java.lang.ClassCastException: us.ny.state.ij.safeact.ask.persistency.impl.CchResponsePersistenceImpl$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$d62edc51 incompatible with

here is stubbing

private PartnerPersistenceImpl mockPartnerPersistenceImpl;

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mockPartnerPersistenceImpl = mock(PartnerPersistenceImpl.class);

}
PowerMockito.doReturn(mockPartnerPersistenceImpl).when(PersistenceFactory.class,"getService",any(RecordTypeEnum.class),any(EntityManager.class));

service.processRequest("DUmmy data");

The return type of PersistenceFactory method is
public static ADRBasePersistenceImpl<?, Long> getService(){}
```

In service class we are type casting to different class to return

PartnerPersistenceImpl parnerPeristenceImpl = (PartnerPersistenceImpl) PersistenceFactory.getService(RecordTypeEnum.SELLERPARTNER, entityManager);

I don't know why mockito not accepting that cast?

Comment: Show the declaration for `mockPartnerPersistenceImpl`.

Comment: private PartnerPersistenceImpl mockPartnerPersistenceImpl;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
 mockPartnerPersistenceImpl = mock(PartnerPersistenceImpl.class);
 
}